# Flutter - How to change state from inside another widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to implement both a Drawer and the Bottom Navigation Bar. The below class NavigationHomeScreen is my home screen and when the user clicks a menu item in the Drawer the Changeindex function updates the `screenView` I would like to know how I can similarly update the `screenView` but from the `BottomNavigationBarApp` using the `onTabTapped` method.

```
class NavigationHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavigationHomeScreenState createState() => _NavigationHomeScreenState();
}

class _NavigationHomeScreenState extends State<NavigationHomeScreen> {
  Widget screenView;
  DrawerIndex drawerIndex;

  @override
  void initState() {
    drawerIndex = DrawerIndex.HOME;
    screenView = const MyHomePage();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: AppTheme.nearlyWhite,
      child: SafeArea(
        top: false,
        bottom: false,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: emptyAppbar(),
          backgroundColor: AppTheme.nearlyWhite,
          body: DrawerUserController(
            screenIndex: drawerIndex,
            drawerWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
            onDrawerCall: (DrawerIndex drawerIndexdata) {
              changeIndex(drawerIndexdata);
              //callback from drawer for replace screen as user need with passing DrawerIndex(Enum index)
            },
            screenView: screenView,
            //we replace screen view as we need on navigate starting screens like MyHomePage, HelpScreen, FeedbackScreen, etc...
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar:BottomNavigationBarApp(context, 1),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void changeIndex(DrawerIndex drawerIndexdata) {
    if (drawerIndex != drawerIndexdata) {
      drawerIndex = drawerIndexdata;
      if (drawerIndex == DrawerIndex.HOME) {
        setState(() {
          screenView = const MyHomePage();
        });
      } else if (drawerIndex == DrawerIndex.Help) {
        setState(() {
          screenView = HelpScreen();
        });
      } else if (drawerIndex == DrawerIndex.FeedBack) {
        setState(() {
          screenView = FeedbackScreen();
        });
      } else if (drawerIndex == DrawerIndex.Invite) {
        setState(() {
          screenView = InviteFriend();
        });
      } else {
        //do in your way......
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
class BottomNavigationBarApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final int bottomNavigationBarIndex;
  final BuildContext context;

  const BottomNavigationBarApp(this. context, this.bottomNavigationBarIndex);

  void onTabTapped(int index) {

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: bottomNavigationBarIndex,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      selectedFontSize: 10,
      selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: CustomColors.BlueDark),
      selectedItemColor: CustomColors.BlueDark,
      unselectedFontSize: 10,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/home.png',
              color: (bottomNavigationBarIndex == 1)
                  ? CustomColors.BlueDark
                  : CustomColors.TextGrey,
            ),
          ),
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/task.png',
              color: (bottomNavigationBarIndex == 0)
                  ? CustomColors.BlueDark
                  : CustomColors.TextGrey,
            ),
          ),
          title: Text('Appointments'),
        ),
      ],
      onTap: onTabTapped,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a reference to a function down to a widget. Something like this:

In your HomeScreen:

```
 void updateScreenView() {
   //Do changes you want here. Dont forget to setState!
  }
```

In your BottomNavigationBarApp (edit: `Function` must start with a capital F):

```
  final int bottomNavigationBarIndex;
  final BuildContext context;
  final Function tapHandler;

  const BottomNavigationBarApp(this. context, this.bottomNavigationBarIndex, this.tapHandler);
```

and then just pass the reference on:

```
bottomNavigationBar:BottomNavigationBarApp(context, 1, updateScreenView),
```

And assign the function to your handler.

```
onTap: () => tapHandler(),
```

Comment: that will call the `tapHandler` before the tap event.

Comment: @Adnankarim Why is that?

Comment: @Adnankarim no, actually I am assigning the onTap event to an anonimous function that calls tapHandler(). That function will not trigger until onTap is raised.

Comment: @BeneTan Thanks for your answer, I have implemented it and selected it as the chosen answer. Just one further question. How could I access the `updateScreenView` function from within the widgets which I  assert as `screenView` such as `MyHomePage()`

where MyHomePage is calling the below class

`class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
}

`

Comment: @user1666453 Its hard for me to read your code right now since I am on my phone. But generally you can pass functions in this way to any other widget. Just pass it to the constructor like above. If you need more help, feel free to update the question with more complete code and I'll have another look. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it and also recommended by the Flutter development team is to use the `provider package` from flutter to manage the state between those widgets.

The top answer does solves your issue if its small app, but as your application grows, you most likely want to change things far up a widget tree which makes functions impractical.