# How can i empty a list in parent after back button is pressed and the user goes back to the parent from new material page route

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried passing the parent as this in the pram and then call parent.parentList.clear();
but after doing so the the Navigator is not popping and neither the list is changing.
nyIdeas?
I tried passing an instance of a function from parent to child but but still the same problem the navigator does not pop.

```
return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        parent.parentList.clear();
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }, child : code.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do this by passing a function down to the child and then calling it before popping. Have a look at my answer here: [Flutter - How to change state from inside another widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61957723/flutter-how-to-change-state-from-inside-another-widget/61957984#61957984)

Hope it helps!

Comment: do you a better way to pass value from a statefulwidget constructor to its state constructor

Comment: i found out that i was doing a very silly thing and that was i had the instance of list in the child and yet i was using a method to clear the list of the parent from child but as i was already passing the same instance of the list to the child because of this reason some how my navigator was not popping when i tried to change the list from calling a method  on parent to clear the list but then i saw that i already had the instance so i used the WillPOP to clear the list and then pop